# How to fill dropdown with JSON data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I try to fill in a dropdown with data from the JSON format but for now the dropdown is empty (no results found...)

I certainly have a mistake and I can not understand where I'm confusing.

I will attach a screen of my API.

I want to get Station and NameStation..

[API for Stations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyrcm.png)

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

function parseStations(stations){
  return stations.map((station) => {
    return { label: station.NameStation, value: station.Station };
  });
}

export default class Weather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        { value: true, label: 'Yes' },
        { value: false, label: 'No' }
      ], stations: [

      ],
      value: null
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.value });
    console.log('Boolean Select value changed to', event.value);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getStations();
  }

  getStations() {
    fetch('http://localhost:56348/api/stations', {
      data: 'Station',
      data: 'NameStation',
      method: "GET"
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ stations: parseStations(res.stations) }))
      //.then(res => this.setState({ stations: res.stations }))
      //.catch(e => )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MasterSection">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="section">Изберете № на станция</div>
          <Select
            onChange={this.onChange}
            //options={this.state.options}
            options={this.state.stations}
            value={this.state.value}
            clearable={false}
          />
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Брой дни назад" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Покажи</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `componentDidMount()` is executed only after `render()` is completed. so there's no way `getStations()` gets executed at the time your UI gets rendered. it is not a good idea to `setState` inside `componentDidMount()` as it triggers re rendering. use `componentWillMount()` instead.
2. correct the typo that Dyo mentioned and use `options={this.state.stations}`

Comment: Fetching data in `componentDidMount()` is a good practice, you can't expect to have the data before the first render using `componentWillMount()` so you'll also need to set an initial state and the rerendering will occur too. (also [componentWillMount will be deprecated in the future](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12152))

Comment: @Dyo I got your point, my concern was only with the `setState`. since `fetch()` is async in nature there's no way to separate them in two different functionality as well. do you think `setState()` inside `componentDidMount()`  is OK to go with?

Comment: Yes it is when you setState in async functions, for sync operations constructor is a better option.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you made a typo naming the prop `stations` instead of `options` :

```
<Select
    onChange={this.onChange}
    options={this.state.stations} // here
    value={this.state.value}
    clearable={false}
/>
```

Edit : you'll need to parse your json first to pass a proper array of objects like this : `[{ label: nameStation, value: Station }]`

Edit 2 : Here's a parser for your data :

```
function parseStations(stations){
  return stations.map((station) => {
    return { label: station.NameStation, value: station.Station };
  });
}
```

You can call this in your async request before setting the state :

```
.then(res => this.setState({ stations: parseStations(res.stations) }))
```

Comment: @ZlatkaPijeva place the parseStations function outside of your component class or declare it as a method (remove "function" if you declare as a method)

Comment: Now I have only two errors: 

Line 19:  'Station' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 19:  'NameStation' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @ZlatkaPijeva you added `[{ label: nameStation, value: Station }]` in your initial state, i wrote this just to illustrate the object format you need to pass to the Select options, just remove this and set the initial state to an empty array like you did before : `stations: [ ]`

Comment: I remove [{ label: nameStation, value: Station }] and leave empty array, but dropdown is still empty (no results found) :(

Comment: @ZlatkaPijeva maybe change `res.stations` to `res.stations.Stations`

Comment: Dropdown is still empty ... :(